# Can I somehow animate foreground color of textblock if foreground is binded to a property?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-animation

If I put Foreground="White" in XAML then the foreground animates ok.
But when I put Foreground="{Binding NumberForeground}" then I get: Cannot animate '(0).(1)' on an immutable object instance.

Here is the code:

```xml
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding NumberText}" Foreground="{Binding NumberForeground}" Visibility="{Binding NumberVisibility}">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource NumberTextBlockStyle}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding EndGame}" Value="True"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding NumberSelected}" Value="True"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="animateNumberTextStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource animateNumberText}" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding EndGame}" Value="False">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="animateNumberTextStoryboard"/>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NumberSelected}" Value="False">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="animateNumberTextStoryboard"/>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

And the animation looks like this:

```xml
<Storyboard x:Key="animateNumberText">
    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBox.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                  Duration="0:0:0.45" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
        <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="#FFFFCA00" KeyTime="0:0:0.15" />
        <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="#FFFF2500" KeyTime="0:0:0.3" />
        <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="#FFCEC100" KeyTime="0:0:0.45" />
    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

Comment: What is the binding target `NumberForeground`? Sounds like it is not a brush.

Comment: NumberForeground is System.Windows.Media.Brush

Comment: I don't think you can both bind and animate like that. I also think you may need a reference to the color. Since all these conditions all seem to be properties in the one viewmodel, i would add a bool property specifically to drive animation and put all the logic in the viewmodel. If i follow intent. I might consider a continuously animating brush. Switch that out.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are animating on a control template, change the `binding` to a `TemplateBinding`. Those types of bindings are optimized for template scenarios and act as a *one-way* type binding.

```
Forground="{TemplateBinding NumberForeground}"
```

See [TemplateBinding Markup Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/templatebinding-markup-extension?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) for more information.